# after upgrade to NextJS 13 Getting Error Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix

Tags: next.js

when i upgrade to NextJs 12 to 13 getting issue

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
_app-f8abd0a73b0d3a9f.js:1038
```

this error only after build and dev mode works fine.
how to fix this issue or debug
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same issue and for me upgrading Mongoose to the latest version (6.7.3 at the time I did it) resolved the issue. I looks like it was one of the mongoose dependencies that was causing the issue.

I'm a yarn user so used the following command to upgrade

```
yarn upgrade mongoose --latest
```